# where is the assignment operator being called in this code?

Tags: c++, assignment-operator

I am told I have to define an assignment operator for my Bullet class, however I was under the impression that the only time you really needed to implement the rule of three was when you explicitly handle memory yourself, such as a pointer class member.

I am actually told that the line that is attempting to invoke the operator= is `std::vector<Bullet> bullets` in the following code. I just don't understand where the assignment operator is being called, and why it's being called. Nowhere am I doing something like `Bullet bullet1 = bullet2`;

**EDIT** - and also, why isn't the default assignment operator suitable? I have no pointer members anywhere in Bullet's hierarchy.

Thanks for the help.

```
#ifndef GUN_H
#define GUN_H

#include "gameObject.h"
#include "Bullet.h"
#include <vector>

class Mesh;

class Gun : public GameObject
{  
    private:
        std::vector<Bullet> bullets; // this line right here

protected:
        virtual void TriggerPulled() = 0;

public:
        Gun(Mesh& mesh);

        virtual ~Gun();

    std::vector<Bullet>& Bullets();
};

#endif
```

this is the source for the same file:

```
#include "Gun.h"
#include "Mesh.h"

Gun::Gun(Mesh& mesh) : GameObject(mesh)
{
    bullets = std::vector<Bullet>();
}

Gun::~Gun() {}

std::vector<Bullet>& Gun::Bullets()
{
return bullets;
}
```

this is bullet:

```
#ifndef BULLET_H
#define BULLET_H

#include "BoundingSphere.h"
#include "helperMethods.h"
#include "GameObject.h"

class Bullet : public GameObject
{
private:
float velocity;
float distance;
D3DXVECTOR3 firedFrom;
BoundingSphere bSphere;

public:
Bullet(D3DXVECTOR3 position, D3DXVECTOR3 rotation, float velocity, D3DXCOLOR colour, Mesh&  mesh);
~Bullet();

BoundingSphere& BulletSphere();
};

#endif
```

BoundingSphere:

```
#ifndef BOUNDING_SPHERE_H
#define BOUNDING_SPHERE_H

#include <d3d10.h>
#include <d3dx10.h>

class Ray;
class BoundingBox;

class BoundingSphere
{
private:
D3DXVECTOR3 centre;
float radius;
public:
BoundingSphere(D3DXVECTOR3 position, float radius);
BoundingSphere();
bool Intersects(BoundingSphere boundingSphere);
bool Intersects(BoundingBox boundingBox);
bool Intersects(Ray ray, D3DXVECTOR3& result);

// getters
const D3DXVECTOR3 Centre();
const float Radius();

// setters
void BoundingSphere::Centre(D3DXVECTOR3 centre);
};

#endif
```

gameObject:

```
#ifndef GAMEOBJECT_H
#define GAMEOBJECT_H

#include <d3d10.h>
#include <d3dx10.h>

class Mesh;

class GameObject 
{
private:
D3DXVECTOR3         scale;
D3DXVECTOR3         rotation;
D3DXVECTOR3         position;
D3DXCOLOR           colour;

D3DXMATRIX matFinal;

Mesh& mesh;

protected:
void Draw(D3DMATRIX matView, D3DMATRIX matProjection);

public:
    GameObject(Mesh& mesh);
virtual ~GameObject();

//getters
const D3DXVECTOR3   Scale();
const D3DXVECTOR3   Rotation();
const D3DXVECTOR3   Position();
const D3DXCOLOR     Colour();

//setters
void Scale(D3DXVECTOR3 scale);
void Rotation(D3DXVECTOR3 rotation);
void Position(D3DXVECTOR3 position);
void Colour(D3DXCOLOR colour);
};

#endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the source you have:

```
bullets = std::vector<Bullet>();
```

The default = operator won't work because `GameObject` has a reference member `mesh` which can't be assigned to. (It's almost like a pointer. It holds an address to an actual class or structure)

Comment: and do you know why the default assignment operator is inadequate for my class?

Comment: @SirYakalot: Yea, I've edited the answer... It's because of the reference member.

Comment: so it would probably do to write an overloaded operator= in GameObject, not even as high up as bullet, right? because the default operator= for Bullet would call the correct overload in GameObject? or is that wrong...?

Answer (score 2):

`GameObject` (and hence all it's derivatives) contains a reference to a `Mesh`.  References are initialized at construction and can't be reassigned so the default assignment operator won't be generated by the compiler in this case.

Answer (score 1):

First, the reason the default `operator=` isn't generated is because
`GameObject` contains a reference (`Mesh& mesh`).  The compiler doesn't
generate an `operator=` for classes which contain one or more references,
nor for classes whose base class doesn't have an `operator=`.

There is no obvious solution in the code you've posted; you can't have a
vector of objects which aren't assignable.

The question is: do you really want to be able to copy these objects.
I'm just guessing from the names, but these sound like objects which 
have identity, or will have identity once the code is finished.  If you
change the position of a `Bullet`, for example, you don't want to have
to track down all of the copies, and change it in them as well—a
`Bullet` has identity.

The solution is to use `std::vector<Bullet*>`, and to allocate all of
the `Bullet` (and everything else which derives from `GameObject`)
dynamically.  Which, if you think about it, is normal: your objects have
lifetimes that are determined by the evolution of the game, and are
independent of scope, or largely of the lifetime of any other object.
`Bullet` may be an exception, since if the `Gun` containing them is
destroyed, the `Bullet` in it should probably be destroyed as well.  But
I'd still handle this in a more generic manner, with the destructor of
`Gun` taking care of the destruction of its `Bullet`.  More generally,
however, when an object is destroyed, you're going to have to find all
of the other objects which refer to it, and remove their pointers to it.
Typically, this requires something like the observer pattern—I've
yet to see any smart pointer which handles this correctly.